# How to install TP-Link TL-WN722N USB Wireless Adapter on Debian Wheezy armhf?

Tags: wireless-networking, debian-wheezy

I have a [TP-Link WN722N](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/cat-11_TL-WN722N.html) USB dongle plugged in:

```
root@udoo-debian-hfp:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.4 (wheezy)
Release:    7.4
Codename:   wheezy

root@udoo-debian-hfp:~# uname -a
Linux udoo-debian-hfp 3.0.35 #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Mar 3 15:17:07 CET 2014 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I identified the device using:

```
root@udoo-debian-hfp:~# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 002 Device 096: ID 0cf3:9271 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
```

According to [wireless.kernel.org](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/ath9k_htc/devices) vendor id:0cf3 product id:9271 uses the ath9k_htc driver. As far as I know, that driver should already be shipped with my current kernel packages. Strangely I cannot find it anywhere:

```
root@udoo-debian-hfp:~# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
vivante                  943  1 
drm                   141896  2 vivante

root@udoo-debian-hfp:~# modinfo ath9k_htc
ERROR: Module ath9k_htc not found.
```

I followed Debian instructions for [ath9k_htc installation](https://wiki.debian.org/ath9k_htc). This had the same result as the previous lsmod. It also didn't show up on the list of network interfaces. I tried rebooting the device and unplugged the USB dongle.

```
root@udoo-debian-hfp:~# iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

usb0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  Mode:Master  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

mon.wlan0  IEEE 802.11bgn  Mode:Monitor  Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
```

wlan0 is the onboard wifi module Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter configured to run hostapd. I'm planning to use the dongle to be a client on another network.

**What can I do at this point to troubleshoot the installation?**

Comment: I was having a very similar question and it turned out that the problem was that I connected the USB wifi to a USB hub that probably didn't have enough power to supply the device. So I connected it to another USB hub that has a separate power cable (it's not powered from USB) and it works now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a long shot, to a quite old question that I hope you've found the answer for...

I did the following to get it working on my system, also Wheezy.

Added the non-free packages to /etc/apt/sources.list

```
apt-get update

apt-get install firmware-atheros

reboot
```

And it showed up in iw list :)

HTHs someone!

Comment: I already resolved my problem. For my case installing the firmware simply wasn't enough, so I also have to install ath9k_htc driver. I put some thorough explanation in http://www.udoo.org/forum/threads/how-to-install-tp-link-tl-wn722n-usb-wireless-adapter.1873/ that link is for embedded board but the same principle apply for any Wheezy system. Thanks for answering, I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Hi, will this work on [TL-WN823N](https://www.tp-link.com/us/download/TL-WN823N.html)?